# Web Scraping Out of Stock Notifier in Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a notifier that will send me an email when an out of stock item is back in stock. So far I have narrowed down how to retrieve the item name and price. However when I tried to use the blue button "Out of stock" next to "Find in store" as a tag, for some reason it retrieves "Add in cart" which appears only when the item is in stock. So I tried using the "OUT OF STOCK" text above the title to set oos_status to True. It's supposed to show as True according to if the i7 configuration on the webpage is Out of Stock, which it was at the time of this writing, but still shows up as False which means it is in stock. Improvements would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 

url = 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/huawei-matebook-x-pro- 
laptop/8n4k86d4j006/4X0P?activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab'

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
uClient = urlopen(req)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

# grabs OOS container
# container_oos = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "cli_badge context-buy- 
box-badge"})
container_oos = page_soup.findAll('div', {"class": "cli_badge context-buy- 
box-badge"})

# grabs price container
container_price_disclaimer = page_soup.findAll("div", {'class': "price- 
disclaimer"})

# grabs name container
container_name = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "m-product-detail-hero- 
product-placement oneui-override"})

# finds text of name, price and out of stock status
name = container_name[0].findAll('h1', {'id': 'page-title'})[0].text.strip()
price = container_price_disclaimer[0].findAll('span')[0].text.strip()
oos_status = False

# Using 'OUT OF STOCK' text above title to decide whether out of stock
if container_oos[0].find('span', {'id': 'out-of-stock-badge'}) == None:
    oos_status = False
elif container_oos[0].find('span', {'id': 'out-of-stock-badge'}) 
[0].text.strip() == 'OUT OF STOCK':
    oos_status = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page loads its data from external site through AJAX calls. If you look at the Firefox/Chrome network inspector, you will see where the calls are going.

This example will get the information about all the SKUs found on the page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/huawei-matebook-x-pro-laptop/8n4k86d4j006/4X0P?activetab=pivot:overviewtab'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')
url = soup.select_one('[data-availability-url]')['data-availability-url']

data = []
for data_availability_id, data_inventory_sku_id, data_sku in zip(soup.select('div.context-configuration-buttons [data-availability-id]'), \
                                                                 soup.select('div.context-configuration-buttons [data-inventory-sku-id]'), \
                                                                 soup.select('div#TechSpec [data-sku]')):
    data.append({
        'availabilityId': data_availability_id['data-availability-id'],
        'distributorId': 9000000013,
        'inventorySkuId': data_inventory_sku_id['data-inventory-sku-id'],
        'preorder': False,
        'productId': soup.select_one('[data-product-id]')['data-product-id'],
        'skuId':data_sku['data-sku'],
    })

r = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=json.dumps(data))
pprint(json.loads(r.text))
```

This will print:

```
{'availabilities': [{'Allocations': {},
                     'availabilityId': '8W2321TK7D0Q',
                     'availableLots': {'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z': {'9000000013': {'deliverByDates': {'0001': '2018-08-09T12:00:00.0000000Z',
                                                                                                          '0004': '2018-08-16T12:00:00.0000000Z'},
                                                                                       'deliveryType': 'Ship',
                                                                                       'hasArbitraryLimitPolicy': 'False',
                                                                                       'inStock': 'False',
                                                                                       'isUnknownDate': 'False',
                                                                                       'onlineOrderAvailable': 'True',
                                                                                       'render': 'True',
                                                                                       'showDateOverride': 'False'}}},
                     'catalogSkuId': 'HB3R',
                     'distributorSkuId': 'QF9-01635',
                     'futureLots': {'2018-08-07T04:00:00.0000000Z': {'9000000013': {'deliverByDates': {'0001': '2018-08-12T12:00:00.0000000Z',
                                                                                                       '0004': '2018-08-19T12:00:00.0000000Z'},
                                                                                    'deliveryType': 'Ship',
                                                                                    'doNotFulfillBeforeDate': 'True',
                                                                                    'hasManuallyConfiguredDeliveryDate': 'False',
                                                                                    'inStock': 'True',
                                                                                    'isProductLaunchFutureLot': 'True',
                                                                                    'isUnknownDate': 'False',
                                                                                    'onlineOrderAvailable': 'True',
                                                                                    'render': 'True',
                                                                                    'showDateOverride': 'False',
                                                                                    'warehouseAllocation': {}}}},
                     'inventoryControlSkuId': 'QF9-01635',
                     'lastWarehouseUpdateTime': '2018-08-04T06:46:49.0000000Z',
                     'productId': '8N4K86D4J006'},
                    {'Allocations': {},
                     'availabilityId': '8WDNCCR153LS',
                     'availableLots': {'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z': {'9000000013': {'deliverByDates': {'0001': '2018-08-09T12:00:00.0000000Z',
                                                                                                          '0004': '2018-08-16T12:00:00.0000000Z'},
                                                                                       'deliveryType': 'Ship',
                                                                                       'hasArbitraryLimitPolicy': 'False',
                                                                                       'inStock': 'False',
                                                                                       'isUnknownDate': 'False',
                                                                                       'onlineOrderAvailable': 'False',
                                                                                       'render': 'True',
                                                                                       'showDateOverride': 'False'}}},
                     'catalogSkuId': '4X0P',
                     'distributorSkuId': 'QF9-01638',
                     'futureLots': {'2018-08-07T04:00:00.0000000Z': {'9000000013': {'deliverByDates': {'0001': '2018-08-12T12:00:00.0000000Z',
                                                                                                       '0004': '2018-08-19T12:00:00.0000000Z'},
                                                                                    'deliveryType': 'Ship',
                                                                                    'doNotFulfillBeforeDate': 'True',
                                                                                    'hasManuallyConfiguredDeliveryDate': 'False',
                                                                                    'inStock': 'False',
                                                                                    'isProductLaunchFutureLot': 'True',
                                                                                    'isUnknownDate': 'False',
                                                                                    'onlineOrderAvailable': 'False',
                                                                                    'render': 'True',
                                                                                    'showDateOverride': 'False',
                                                                                    'warehouseAllocation': {}}},
                                    '2018-09-04T04:00:00.0000000Z': {'9000000013': {'deliverByDates': {'0001': '2018-09-09T12:00:00.0000000Z',
                                                                                                       '0004': '2018-09-16T12:00:00.0000000Z'},
                                                                                    'deliveryType': 'Ship',
                                                                                    'doNotFulfillBeforeDate': 'True',
                                                                                    'hasManuallyConfiguredDeliveryDate': 'False',
                                                                                    'inStock': 'False',
                                                                                    'isProductLaunchFutureLot': 'False',
                                                                                    'isUnknownDate': 'False',
                                                                                    'onlineOrderAvailable': 'False',
                                                                                    'render': 'True',
                                                                                    'showDateOverride': 'False',
                                                                                    'warehouseAllocation': {}}}},
                     'inventoryControlSkuId': 'QF9-01638',
                     'lastWarehouseUpdateTime': '2018-08-04T06:46:49.0000000Z',
                     'productId': '8N4K86D4J006'}],
 'inStock': 'False'}
```

As you see, some SKUs (configurations) are on stock, some aren't. It depends on you for which configuration are you searching for, there are multiple on that page url.

Comment: Thanks so much. Why did you set preorder to always False? And how come it prints so much more data than was available from the for loop? Did you parse this information from within the html of the webpage, or the external inventory webpage (because I cannot seem to load the inventory webpage)?

Comment: @yottamamba I've just looked to Firefox network inspector and saw the page always sends this parameter set to `False`. It's part of their API, which has the URL found in tag with parameter `data-availability-url`. I don't know the specifics of this API though, all is only from what I saw in the Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am trying to retrieve the bits of information I need, namely the 'catalogSkuId': '4X0P' and 'inStock': 'False' associated with it, but I am confused by the last two lines of your code. Do you have suggestions as to how I can go about doing this?

Comment: @yottamamba last 2 lines in my code will send POST request to their API with parameters stored as JSON payload. The `json.loads(r.text)` will decode response to python dictionary. you can do `my_dict = json.loads(r.text)` and then access `my_dict` as any Python dictioary, for example `print(my_dict['availabilities'])`

Answer (score 2):

If you monitor the web traffic (F11->Network Tools in Chrome), you'll see that that information isn't actually located 'within' the page - it's loaded with a POST request to an internal `inventory` endpoint:
[image: the request]

[image: the response]

The above pictures show the POST request and the response, respectively. So, because this data isn't generated from the actual GET request to the laptop's page, you have two options:

1. Mimic the POST request. This is borderline unethical, because Microsoft has the system set up in this way to minimize unnecessary traffic.  On the other hand (and this may earn me some downvotes), I don't think something like this is going to affect Microsoft's servers too much.  Mimicking the POST request would require you to find out what is sent to the server and how to structure that request.  All of this information can be found within the POST request that I posted if you scroll through it and use your noggin.
2. Use `selenium` (the Python module, not the piece of software).  This uses a browser, so it'll generate exactly what you see in the browser, though you'll have to give it a second to allow the site to make that POST request.  After that, you could use BeautifulSoup as you were before to scrape the relevant information. This way would be significantly easier in terms of time that it'll take if you don't know how to replicate POST requests.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much for the insight